# Need a workaround for known issue with os.replace() function on Windows

Tags: python, firebase, file

I'm working with a script that downloads files from cloud firebase storage, stores them locally in a folder "assets", and renames the references to those files internally on each target .md note file.

The issue is just with the last step, where the temp file with the new reference needs to replace the old file. I receive the error "PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

I tried a few things, but eventually found this source: https://bugs.python.org/issue46003
It seems there is a persistent bug with the os.replace() function on Windows, and I don't know how to implement a workaround in my context. I considered attempting to add delay as suggested in the thread, but this doesn't seem like the best option since there are hundreds of references I need to modify.

Here is the code:
(the area in question is at the end "if os.path.exists(fullTempFilePath)..."

```
import re
import glob
import os
import requests
import calendar
import time

vaultDir = '/Users/kacar/Firebase Temp/Firebase-Test'

firebaseShort = 'none'
fullRead = 'none'
fileFullPath = ''
fullTempFilePath = ''
i = 0
ext = ''

/# Walk through all files in all directories within the specified vault directory
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(vaultDir):
    for file in files:
        # Open file in directory
        fileFullPath = os.path.join(subdir,file)
        fhand = open(fileFullPath, errors='ignore')
        for line in fhand:
            # Download the Firebase file and save it in the assets folder
            if 'firebasestorage' in line:
                try:
                    # If it's a PDF, it will be in the format {{pdf: link}}
                    if '{{pdf:' in line:
                        link = re.search(r'https://firebasestorage(.*)\?alt(.*)\}', line)
                    else:
                        link = re.search(r'https://firebasestorage(.*)\?alt(.*)\)', line)
                    firebaseShort = 'https://firebasestorage' + link.group(1) # https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/firescript-577a2.appspot.com/o/imgs%2Fapp%2FDownloadMyBrain%2FLy4Wel-rjk.png
                    firebaseUrl = link.group(0)[:-1] # https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/firescript-577a2.appspot.com/o/imgs%2Fapp%2FDownloadMyBrain%2FLy4Wel-rjk.png?alt=media&token=0fbafc8f-0a47-4720-9e68-88f70803ced6
                    # Download the file locally
                    r = requests.get(firebaseUrl)
                    timestamp = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
                    # Get file extension of file. Ex: .png; .jpeg
                    reg = re.search(r'(.*)\.(.+)', firebaseShort[-5:]) # a.png / .jpeg
                    ext = '.' + reg.group(2) # .jpeg
                    # Create assets folder if it doesn't exist
                    if not os.path.exists(vaultDir + '/assets'):
                        os.makedirs(vaultDir + '/assets')
                    # Create new local file out of downloaded firebase file
                    newFilePath = 'assets/' + str(timestamp) + '_' + str(i) + ext
                    # print(firebaseUrl + '>>>' + newFilePath)
                    with open(vaultDir + '/' + newFilePath,'wb') as output_file:
                        output_file.write(r.content)
                except AttributeError: # This is to prevent the AttributeError exception when no matches     are returned
                    continue
                # Save Markdown file with new local file link as a temp file
                # If there is already a temp version of a file, open that.
                fullTempFilePath = vaultDir + '/temp_' + file
                if os.path.exists(fullTempFilePath):
                    fullRead = open(fullTempFilePath, errors='ignore')
                else:
                    fullRead = open(fileFullPath, errors='ignore')
                data = fullRead.read()
                data = data.replace(firebaseUrl,newFilePath)
                fullRead.close()
                with open(fullTempFilePath,'wt') as temp_file:
                    temp_file.write(data)
                    i = i + 1
                if os.path.exists(fullTempFilePath):
                    path = os.replace(fullTempFilePath,fileFullPath)

        # Close file
        fhand.close()
```

Comment: `fhand` is an open file handle to the same `fileFullPath`.  You can't have an open file handle during the replace.  `open` with `errors='ignore'` is also a bad idea when working with binary files.  You're going to corrupt them by decoding them as whatever the default encoding is and ignoring decoding errors.  Use `open(filename, 'rb')` to read a binary file.

Comment: You're trying to replace the file that you're in the middle of reading, each time through the loop. This doesn't really make sense to me. You should just set a variable to the file you want to replace into this file, and call `os.replace()` after the loop when you've closed the file.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I moved the final statement outside of the main loop and that resolved the issue. @MarkTolonen regarding the errors='ignore' addition, this was a special case where the files (mostly UTF-8 markdown files, couldn't use binary?) being modified were exported from another piece of software, and the encoding was inconsistent. The errors were not significant in my tests to the goal I was aiming for.